# Fast way to check two lists for consistency

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, list

I need to check two lists for consistency, e.g to return `True` if the first list dosen't contain elements, which are not present in second list, and if the `count` of similar elements is the same. By now, I came out with following:

```
def is_consistent(spec_a, spec_b):
    for a in spec_a:
        if spec_a.count(a) != spec_b.count(a):
            return False
    return True
```

But I need to do it in a loop, so I wonder, can it be faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question properly, perhaps you could use a `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
def is_consistent(spec_a, spec_b):
    c1 = Counter(spec_a)
    c2 = Counter(spec_b)
    result = c1 - c2
    return all(result[key] == 0 for key in c1)
```

The loop is unavoidable -- It will always be there in some form or another.  In fact, I have 3 loops here.  (one in each `Counter` and then the most obvious one at the end).  However, the operation that my solution avoids is the `.count` which is another implicit loop nested *inside* another loop.

Nested loops are generally the ones you want to eliminate because if the outer loop iterates N times and the inner loop iterates N times than you have a total of N*N iterations.  Compare that to my solution which has only ~3*N iterations (3 loops with about N iterations each).  If `N` is big, you can see how this would lead to a large number of operations being saved.

Comment: In fact, this now has three loops instead of two—each `Counter` constructor has to loop over its input, and then there's a loop in the generator expression passed to `all`. The advantage is that there are three flat loops run in series, instead of one loop with a nested loop inside of it. So, if you have N elements, it takes 3 * N steps, instead of N * N, which is a huge win if N is not tiny.

Comment: Obviously _you_ know this (and also know that the third loop is actually less than N, and that both versions short-circuit…); I was explaining it for the benefit of a novice who might not.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be in the answer; the comment is there if anyone needs more information, while the answer is nice and simple for anyone who doesn't.

Comment: @abarnert -- Oops, too late :-P

Comment: In retrospect, since "can it be faster?" is the OP's main question, I guess it's reasonable to explain why it's faster in the answer.